# How to change the position of an element in a list?

Tags: python

I want to move the smallest integer in the list down one index in the list.
For example:

```
>>> move_small_value([5,4,3,2,1])
[1,5,4,3,2]
```

Comment: NYRAHHH, please clarify. Your text states that you want it to move down *one* index in the list which would suggest a result of `5,4,3,1,2`. However, your example of `1,5,4,3,2` suggests you want to move the lowest to the *start* of the list. We could normally use the title as a tie-breaker but it could go either way in this case. So we need you to be more specific as to what you want. Also, what do you want to do with the list `5 4 1 2 1`? Which `1` should be moved?

Answer (score 1):

```
def move_small_value(L):
    min_idx = L.index(min(L))
    return [L[min_idx]] + L[:min_idx] + L[min_idx + 1:]
```

Comment: OP wants a torroidal right shift. This would fail if the example's output were given as the input, as the expected output would then be `[5,1,4,3,2]`. PS: I'm not the downvoter

Comment: I downvoted originally as you were adding a list to None (L + L.remove) ... down vote is still in place as this function is currently destructive to the input L

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, How do you get that from the question?

Comment: `I want to move [it] down one integer` <- seems to say `move it one to the right (i.e. right shift)`. The example demonstrates a torroidal-ness of the right shift, as the min value is at the last index. Anyway, I've posted an answer based on my interpretation. If it gets an upvote/accept, we'll know for sure

Comment: @donkopotamus, it's not destructive now :) Still not sure I agree inspectorG4dget's interpretation is obvious from a single example

Comment: @JohnLaRooy downvote removed ... and I think its completely unclear what they're asking!

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
def move_small_value(L):
    small_idx = min(enumerate(L), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    answer = L[:small_idx] + [L[small_idx+1]] + [L[small_idx]] + L[small_idx+2:]
    return answer
```

Comment: You can also use `min(range(len(L)), key=L.__getitem__)` to find the minimum index

Comment: @JohnLaRooy: This is true. Also, why the change in username? I quite liked your old one